# React.JS - Can't put inputRef.current.value into JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

But in console.log from `useEffect` I get correct info.

How can I fix it?

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('Default text');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('value: ', inputRef.current.value);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {/*<h4>{inputRef.current.value}</h4>*/}
      
      <h3>{inputValue}</h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={inputRef}
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Breaking example:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('Default text');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('value: ', inputRef.current.value);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{inputRef.current.value}</h4>
      
      <h3>{inputValue}</h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={inputRef}
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `inputRef` is initially null. Until the ref has been assigned to something, there is no `current` property

Comment: No, it does not works if I write: "<h4>{inputRef.current}</h4>"

Comment: Brian is correct. I propose `{inputRef.current && <h4>{inputRef.current.value}</h4>}` could do it

Comment: OK, but why I get correct info into console from useEffect()?

Comment: Because `useEffect` runs after the component has been mounted (and every render after that since there is no second argument), so by the time `useEffect` runs, `current` has been assigned the a value. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) "it runs both after the first render and after every update", which means `ref={inputRef}` has already happened.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! I is working

Answer (score 0):

That's because

> By default, effects run after every completed render, but you can choose to fire them only when certain values have changed. [useEffect doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Actually, React guarantees to have `inputted.current` in useEffect call, but it needs one render for getting DOM reference.
You can not use `inputRef` in the first render phase cause it simply doesn't get its value yet.